# What is the difference between this two declarations " int **matrix " and " int matrix [] [] "?

Tags: c, pointers

What I learnt from C language is that 
int **matrix = matrix is a pointer to pointer to int 
when we want to create a matrix we will malloc a set of contigus pointers !
so here is the first pointer pointing to 1 pointer to an int or it can point to a set of pointers which are pointing to an int ( the first pointer will of course point to the address of the first pointer )

Brievely pointing to 1 pointer (only one ) is it the same as pointing to first pointer from a set of pointers ?

I think the answer resides inside this question What is exactly an array of something  ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Brievely"

Comment: yep interesting because int ** matrix is a pointer to a pointer and when we do malloc(sizeof(int*) * X) it becomes a pointer to an array   ambiguous :/ !!

Comment: @user12448: Hm. What do you mean?

Comment: @Deduplicator  I mean:  Is saying **pointer to a pointer to** is the same as saying **pointer to an array** ? becuase **array** is in itself a **pointer to** if I am right of course !

Comment: there is a tiny difference, sizeof(). sizeof pointer is always constant. sizeof array of pointers will depend on array size.

Comment: @Anonymous: That's only the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: when we allocate a contigus memory and then make a pointer pointing to the first case of that allocation does it make it an array ?

Comment: @user12448, although they are structurally identical, the compiler will deal with them differently.

Answer (score 6):

Pointers and arrays are fundamentally different, especially wrt. to their behavior with `sizeof()` and wrt. what they allocate. However, they can sometimes be used interchangeably, because both essentially represent an address.

If you dynamically allocate memory, you will receive a pointer, which points to the beginning of a chunk of memory. If you allocate memory of a size that represents a multiple of a type's size, it should be intuitively clear that you can store as many elements of one type there, as you have allocated space for. Since C pointer arithmetic interprets `*(p + n)` - which is the same as `p[n]` and `n[p]` - as an access to the address of `p` plus `n` times the size of an element of the type `p` points to, it should now be easier to understand that you can interpret the pointer as the beginning of an array.

For your case, that means you can interpret `int **p` as a pointer to an `int`-pointer. Past the memory of this pointer, `n` more `int` pointers may follow, while every one of these pointers represents the address of an `int`, past which, once again, `n` more `ints` may follow. Thus, even though `int **p` is actually a pointer to a pointer of type `int`, it is possible to interpret it as two-dimensional array. How many elements past your pointer belong to the array is something that you cannot know from neither an array not a pointer, which is why you will usually have a `n_size` and/or `m_size` argument or something similar.

In the beginning I said that you can "sometimes" treat them as the same. To make this explicit, you can use pointers and arrays interchangeably in these cases:

1. When passed to a function a `type[]` "decays" to a `type *` e.g. `f(type *a)`
2. If accessing elements with the `[]` operator, `a[i]` always resolves to `*(a + i)`
3. When they occur in an expression, e.g. `++a`

cf: [van der Linden - Deep C](http://books.google.de/books?id=9f9uAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA242&lpg=PA242&dq=when%20are%20pointer%20and%20array%20the%20same%20van%20der%20linden&source=bl&ots=UI2or4kIes&sig=W7bXm2ATFWXO0QIE2Qy_rQXrV4Y&hl=de&sa=X&ei=jboIVOqmKsH4yQOp_YLAAQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=when%20are%20pointer%20and%20array%20the%20same%20van%20der%20linden&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

if you want a quick answer try making this tiny program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int matrix[2][3];
   int **m;
   m=malloc(sizeof(int *)*2);
   m[0]=malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
   m[1]=malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
   m=matrix;

   return 0;
}
```

The compiler will answer you that the two declarations are different. In fact: 
[image: warining]

Comment: You can leave out the allocations since they leak anyway. If you still include them, then illustrate that the dimensions need not be the same for both m[x].

Comment: I didn't get a warning when testing it with one dimensial array !! This is really confusing !!

Comment: maybe because an array decays to a pointer !